# Editing html in PHP dom - Changing CSS to Img attribute

Tags: php, html, css, dom, domdocument

My WYSIWYG editor (Summernote) get me so close to what I need to send html-encoded emails with images, except it uses CSS widths and heights instead of img width and height attributes.

```
<?php
$html = '<p><img src="image1.png" style="width: 770px; height:300px;"><br></p>
<p><img src="image2.png" style="width: 300px;"><br></p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    foreach ($img->attributes as $attr) {
      $name = $attr->nodeName;
      $value = $attr->nodeValue;
      echo "Attribute '$name' :: '$value'<br />";
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

Almost there.  Output of above:

```
Attribute 'src' :: 'image1.png'
Attribute 'style' :: 'width: 770px; height:300px;'

Attribute 'src' :: 'image2.png'
Attribute 'style' :: 'width: 300px;'
```

I just need to figure out how to come up the appropriate img attributes and their values, but how then to write those attributes back into the img tags?

Comment: its in the docs ... http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createattribute.php

Answer (score 0):

I ditched the dom method and came up with this.  Works great.

```
$message = '<p><img src="email_attachments/image1.png" style="width: 770px; height:300px;">
1234567890</p><p><img src="email_attachments/image2.png" style="width: 50%;"><br></p>'; //incoming html from SummerNote

$pos = 0; //starting position
for ($i = 1; $i <= substr_count($message, '<img '); $i++) { //loop through the images

    $locStart = strpos($message, '<img ', $pos); //starting position of this image tag
    $locEnd = strpos($message, '>', $locStart);  //end of this image tag
    $pos = $locEnd; //set starting position for next image, if any

    $tag = substr($message, $locStart, ($locEnd-($locStart-1)) );  //this is just the image tag

    $widthStart = strpos($tag, 'width: ');  // start of width value in the inline css, i.e., 100px or 25%
    $widthEnd = strpos($tag, ';', $widthStart);  //end of width value

    $width = substr($tag, $widthStart, ($widthEnd-($widthStart-1)) );  //just the value of the css width
    $width = str_replace('width: ', '', $width); // replace 'width: '
    $width = str_replace('px;', '', $width);     // replace 'px;'
    $width = str_replace(';', '', $width);       // replace ';' if % is used

    $message = substr_replace($message, ' width="'.$width.'" ', $locEnd, 0);  //add width value to the image tag    
}
$message = str_replace('src="email_attachments/', 'src="cid:', $message);  //change the folder name to cid

result is: <p><img src="cid:image1.png" style="width: 770px; height:300px;" width="770" >
1234567890</p><p><img src="cid:image2.png" style="width: 50%;" width="50%" ><br></p>
```